# Hide a specific column if a variable is true in material angular data table

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Good morning I have the following question, I have a data table which I get the data that is in it by consuming api rest, the question is that I want to hide a specific column of the same table depending on the value of a variable where its value will be collected in the authentication to enter the application, but I would like to know what method there is to hide a column in a data table depending on the condition of a variable.

My code

The column to hide is the **Com. Snmp**
[image]

```
<div class="col-11 mx-auto">

        <div class="search-div" >
              <button  class="btn btn-primary"  (click)="onCreate()" [hidden]='permiso2'>Crear Equipo</button>&nbsp;&nbsp; 
              <!-- -->
              <button class="btn btn-warning"(click)="onExport()">Descargar Datos</button>&nbsp;&nbsp; 
            <mat-form-field class="search-form-field">
                <input matInput (keyup)="DoFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filtrar">
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
                                                    <!--Data Table-->
          <div>  
              <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" align="center" [hidden]="isLoading" >  

                  <!-- Position Column -->
                  <ng-container matColumnDef="id_equipo">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>ID Equipo</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.id_equipo}}</td>
                  </ng-container>

                  <!-- Name Column -->
                  <ng-container matColumnDef="nombre">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Nombre Equipo</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" >{{element.nombre}}</td>
                  </ng-container>

                  <!-- Weight Column -->
                  <ng-container matColumnDef="vendedor">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Vendedor</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.vendedor}}</td>
                  </ng-container>

                  <!-- Symbol Column -->
                  <ng-container matColumnDef="ip_gestion">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>IP Gestión</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.ip_gestion}}</td>
                  </ng-container>

                  <ng-container matColumnDef="tipo">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Tipo</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.tipo}} </td>
                  </ng-container>

                  <ng-container matColumnDef="localidad">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Localidad</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.localidad}}</td>
                  </ng-container>

                  <!-- <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
                  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr> -->

                  <ng-container matColumnDef="categoria">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Categoria</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.categoria}}</td>
                  </ng-container>

                   <ng-container matColumnDef="com_snmp">
                      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef matTooltip="Comunidad SNMP de Lectura" matTooltipPosition="above">Com. SNMP</th>
                      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.com_snmp}}</td>
                    </ng-container>

                  <ng-container matColumnDef="ultima_actualizacion">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Ultima Actualización </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.ultima_actualizacion | date:'d/M/yyyy, h:mm a'}}</td>
                  </ng-container>

                  <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Acciones</th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                    <fa-icon [icon]=icon_edit class="btn btn-success" (click)=onEdit(element) matTooltip="Editar" matTooltipPosition="left" [hidden]='permiso2'></fa-icon>&nbsp;
                    <!-- -->
                    <fa-icon [icon]=icon_delete class="btn btn-danger" (click)=onDelete(element) matTooltip="Eliminar" matTooltipPosition="right" [hidden]='!delete_permiso'></fa-icon>

                    </td>
                  </ng-container>

                  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
                  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>

              </table>        
                  <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5,10,20,50]" showFirstLastButtons [hidden]="isLoading"></mat-paginator>          
          </div>

                                                <!--Spinner Para la Carga de Datos-->
                <ng-container *ngIf="isLoading">
                  <mat-spinner class="spinner-container"></mat-spinner>
                  <br>
                  <p>Su data esta siendo cargada, por favor espere</p>
                </ng-container>           
  </div>
<br>
```

My equipo.ts

```
displayedColumns: string[] = ['id_equipo', 'nombre', 'vendedor', 'ip_gestion','tipo','localidad','categoria','com_snmp','ultima_actualizacion','actions',]; // Arreglo con los nombres de las columnas a mostrar por el DataTable
            dataSource:any;


RenderDataTable() {
                this.isLoading=true;
                this.PrtgService.getAllElements(this.table).subscribe(  
                  (res) => {  
                      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
                      this.dataSource.data = res.sort((a, b) => a.vendedor.localeCompare(b.vendedor));
                      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator; // Paginando el DataSource
                      this.isLoading=false;   

                },
ngOnInit() {
            this.RenderDataTable()
                                   }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make use of `displayedColumns` variable to show hide cols on basis of your condition. Remove column that you need from `displayedColumns` as shown below:

```
ngOnInit(){
 if(yourCond == true){
   displayedColumns: string[] = ['id_equipo', 'nombre', 'vendedor', 'ip_gestion','tipo','localidad','categoria','ultima_actualizacion','actions']; 
   }
}
```

Comment: @Arturo29 Cool!

Answer (score 1):

You can use ***ngIf** on that specific column on which you want to apply some condition. Declare a variable **IsTrue** and assign it a value of false by default. And in your logic when you want to display this column assign this variable value true.

```html
<ng-container matColumnDef="com_snmp" *ngIf="isTrue">
                  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef matTooltip="Comunidad SNMP de Lectura" matTooltipPosition="above">Com. SNMP</th>
                  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.com_snmp}}</td>
                </ng-container>
```

Answer (score 1):

to hide dynamically material table columns;

```
if (this.userRole != 'Admin') {
  this.displayedColumns = [
    'requestNo',
    'createdAt',
    'spareName',
    'spareNum',
    'spareAttr',
    'approvedQuantity',
    'quantity',
    'requestedBy',
    'department',
  ];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Puedes también solo agregar una clase en el CSS Y Consumir esta en el HTML, esto me funciona en Angular Material. Espero que les sirva

```css
.hide_element{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
 <ng-container matColumnDef="recibo"class="hide_element">
        <mat-header-cell mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef  class="hide_element">Recibo</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="hide_element"> {{element.recibo}} </mat-cell>
 </ng-container>
```

Comment: please use English to answer to question